How can I trigger a method to update NavMenu from a blazor page in WASM?
I have a Blazor WASM Client e-commerce application where I'm showing cart counts in the NavMenu. I'm trying to call the GetCartCount() method from the OrderConfirmation blazor page after payment has been completed to make the cart count zero, but I'm unable to do so. Can someone please help me figure out how to achieve this? I came across sort of similar posts here but couldn't get how to implement.
@inject ISyncLocalStorageService _localStorage
@inject ICartService _cartService
@implements IDisposable
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Walk in Style</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        
          <li class="nav-item p-0">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/cart">
                            <span class="p-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-cart"></i> (@GetCartCount())
                            </span>
        </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <AuthorizeView>
                  <Authorized>
                       <li class="nav-item p-0">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span class="p-2">
                                Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name
                            </span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item p-0">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="logout">
                            <span class="p-2">
                                Logout
                            </span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                  </Authorized>
                  <NotAuthorized>
                       <li class="nav-item p-0">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="register">
                            <span class="p-2">
                                Register
                            </span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item p-0">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
                            <span class="p-2">
                                Login
                            </span>
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                  </NotAuthorized>
              </AuthorizeView>
             
          </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _cartService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
        
    }
   
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cartService.OnChange-=StateHasChanged;
        
    }
    private int GetCartCount(){
        var cart = _localStorage.GetItem<List<ShoppingCart>>(SD.ShoppingCart);
        return cart?.Count ?? 0;
    }
}

I am trying to call GetCartCount from OrderConfirmation razor page after payment has been completed to make the cart count zero. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do it.
@page "/OrderConfirmation"
@inject ILocalStorageService _localStorage
@inject IOrderService _orderService
<div class="container">
    @if (IsProcessing)
{
    <div style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-50px;margin-left:-100px;">
        <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        @if (Order.OrderHeader.Status == SD.Status_Confirmed)
        {
            <div class="row mt-4 pt-4">
             <div class="col-10 offset-1 text-center">
                <h2 class="text-warning">Order Confirmed</h2>
                <p>Your order has been placed successfully with order id : @Order.OrderHeader.Id</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-8 offset-2">
                 <img src="/images/confirmation.jpg" width="100%" style="border-radius:30px;" alt="Confirmed"/>
             </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
             <div class="row mt-4 pt-4">
                <div class="col-10 offset-1 text-center">
                <h2 class="text-danger">Order Issue!</h2>
                <p>Your order had payment issue please contact us with Order ID:  @Order.OrderHeader.Id</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">
                <img src="/images/confirmation.jpg" width="100%" style="border-radius:30px;" alt="Not Confirmed"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
@code {
    private bool IsProcessing { get; set; } = false;
    private OrderDTO Order { get; set; }
   
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        IsProcessing = true;
        Order = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<OrderDTO>(SD.Local_OrderDetails);
        
        var updatedOrder = await _orderService.MarkPaymentSuccessful(Order.OrderHeader);
        if (updatedOrder.Status==SD.Status_Confirmed)
        {
            Order.OrderHeader.Status=updatedOrder.Status;
            await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.ShoppingCart);
            await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.Local_OrderDetails);            
        }
            IsProcessing = false;
    }
}

I want to trigger or find another way to make something if SD.Status_Confirmedto update the navmenu.
Here is CartService where I increment/decrement the number of items in the cart and reflect it to the navmenu count.
public class CartService : ICartService
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
    public event Action OnChange;

    public CartService(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _localStorage = localStorageService;
    }

  
    public async Task IncrementCart(ShoppingCart cartToAdd)
    {
        var cart = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<ShoppingCart>>(SD.ShoppingCart);
        bool itemInCart = false;

        if (cart==null)
        {
            cart = new List<ShoppingCart>();
        }
        foreach(var obj in cart)
        {
            if(obj.ProductId==cartToAdd.ProductId && obj.ProductPriceId==cartToAdd.ProductPriceId)
            {
                itemInCart = true;
                obj.Count+=cartToAdd.Count;
            }
        }
        if (!itemInCart)
        {
            cart.Add(new ShoppingCart()
            {
                ProductId = cartToAdd.ProductId,
                ProductPriceId = cartToAdd.ProductPriceId,
                Count = cartToAdd.Count
            });
        }
        await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(SD.ShoppingCart, cart);
        OnChange.Invoke();

    }

    public async Task DecrementCart(ShoppingCart cartToDecrement)
    {
        var cart = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<ShoppingCart>>(SD.ShoppingCart);
       
        //if count is 0 or 1 then we remove the item
        for(int i=0; i<cart.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cart[i].ProductId==cartToDecrement.ProductId && cart[i].ProductPriceId==cartToDecrement.ProductPriceId)
            {
                if(cart[i].Count==1 || cartToDecrement.Count==0)
                {
                    cart.Remove(cart[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    cart[i].Count -= cartToDecrement.Count;
                }
            }
        }
        
        await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(SD.ShoppingCart, cart);
        OnChange.Invoke();
    }
}

I added this method to the service;
public async Task ClearCart()
{
    await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.ShoppingCart);
    await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.Local_OrderDetails);

    OnChange.Invoke();
}

And called it inside of OrderConfirmation:
...
if (updatedOrder.Status==SD.Status_Confirmed)
{
    Order.OrderHeader.Status=updatedOrder.Status;

    await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.ShoppingCart);
    await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync(SD.Local_OrderDetails);
    await _cartService.ClearCart();
}
...

Seems working as I wanted. I wonder if this is a good practice?

Use <SectionOutlet /> in combination with <SectionContent />
An example using the .net 8 Web Application template:
In the menu add:
<SectionOutlet @rendermode=InteractiveWebAssembly SectionName="nav-bar"/>

On the counter page:
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<SectionContent SectionName="nav-bar">
    @currentCount
</SectionContent>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}


Is this applicable to .Net 6 the old one?

No but you can do the same thing by passing renderfragments. However if your resulting to do all the hard work I would use an injected service and just pass the data. I don't have time to write and example today I'm sure there are examples here.

I have a cart service where I increment/decrement the number of items and reflect the count to the nav menu. But I am not sure how to implement a logic for after checkout in this service.

I added a method to the service and it seems working as I wanted. Is this a good practise?

Injection is fine. It helps with testing as well.
